# Property `packagesToScan` not working

Tags: java, spring

I have an entity class whose full name is `foo.bar.Book`. I wrote a simple test class as below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"/beans-test.xml", "/dataSource-test.xml"})
public class BookTest {

    @PersistenceContext EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setTitle("Hello");

        entityManager.persist(book);
    }
}
```

In the `dataSource-test.xml`, I have

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence-test.xml" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="tempWarPU" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="foo.bar.*" />
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Note that there is a property `packagesToScan` above, which is supposed to enable Spring to find `foo.bar.Book`. However, that didn't happen. I got an error like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: foo.bar.Book
```

Nevertheless, the test will pass if I add the line below to the `persistence-test.xml` that shows in the bean definition of `entityManagerFactory`:

```
<class>foo.bar.Book</class>
```

So, it seems to me the `packagesToScan` property is not really working. Is that true? If so, how can I make Spring to auto-scan for entity classes? I tried putting `<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>` in the `persistence-test.xml`, but that didn't help.

Thank you very much.

**update**

The version of Spring is `4.0.0.RELEASE`.

I also tried non-wildcard way as below, but no luck.

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="foo.bar" />
```

Comment: The properties is `packagesToScan` and it takes package names, not a wildcard.

Answer (score 3):

```
<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="test-pu" />
<property name="packagesToScan">
    <list>
        <value>abc.xyz.entity.**.*</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

This two properties won't work together. 
1. persistence.xml exist and LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean specifies persistenceUnitName
2. LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean defines persistence unit with scan.

If You want to check this behawior debug: org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager
methods: readPersistenceUnitInfos, buildDefaultPersistenceUnitInfo

Made my tests on spring 3.2.8

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it looks a bit confusing to me. So, when you say "these two properties", which two properties exactly are you referring to? Moreover, are you saying that the `persistenceUnitName` should define a name rather than refer a name from the persistence xml? In any case, some clarification is much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following line in your configuration file

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="foo.bar" />
```